# when updating item with changed embedded docs in Mongoose, these embedded docs don't update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm doing the following using Mongoose:

```
that.model.update({_id: dao._id}, dao,  { upsert: true }, cb);
```

Where `dao` is a mongoose representation containing (among other things) a couple of embedded documents. As a test I've deleted a couple of the embedded docs from the array before calling the update-method above.

The result is that the change to the array of embedded docs IS NOT persisted.

Anything I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing something similar as proposed in the following issue: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/571

For completeness some background which led to the problem.

I'm using DDD repositories which are populated on app-start. Under the hood this fetches Mongoose-objects (which are treate as DAOs in my situation) and are translated to domainobjects, which are cached in the repository. I need this separation between domainobjects and mongoose-objects, don't ask.

This means that `getById`, `getAll` and all other public interfaces of the repo work with domainobjects and not with mongoose-objects.

When doing things like `add` or `update` on the repo this internally only updates the in-mem cache (which, again, only uses domainobjects instead of mongoose-objects)

Only when doing `commit` on the repo does the possibly changed collection of domainobjects get persisted. This is done by creating NEW Mongoose-objects instead of fetching Existing mongoose-objects and updating those.

This is why I can't use `dao.save()` since, when I'm saving a different (just created) mongoose-object while a mongoose-object with the same id may possibly already exist in Mongo, it throws a duplicate id error.

Some relevant snippet from by code illustrating the solution:

> var dao = that.createDAO(domainobject);
>
> ```
>       //https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/571
>       // Convert the Model instance to a simple object using Model's 'toObject' function
>       // to prevent weirdness like infinite looping...
>       var upsertData = dao.toObject();
>
>       // Delete the _id property, otherwise Mongo will return a "Mod on _id not allowed" error
>       delete upsertData._id;
>
>       that.model.update({_id: dao._id}, upsertData,  { upsert: true }, cb);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to be certain w/o seeing more code, but if `dao` is a Mongoose model instance, you should be calling `dao.save(cb);` instead.

Comment: that gives a `MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index` on existing docs. That's the reason I went with what I described. Perhaps there's a `dao.save` option to overwrite in case of duplicate key that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Geert-Jan Sounds like there may be a problem elsewhere.  Posting a minimal example would help.

Comment: The duplicate error indicates the data being saved violates an unique index. The data must be corrected before Mongo will accept your update.

Comment: @Aaron: yeah but the violated unique index is the '_id' field, which is always the case when saving an already existing document? Should this normally work? Ahh, perhaps I know... The save-call is done as part of commiting a cached repository. This involves creating a new mongoose-model from a domainobject (present in the cached repo) and persisting that. In other words each time I save the same domainobject, what actually happens is that a new mongoose-model is created under the hood which is saved. Perhaps there's a flag `new` in this model causing the trouble?

Comment: hard to say without seeing the actual code. english is buggy.

Comment: Yeah reading back, I'm rambling all over. Sorry about that. I've found the answer in issue https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/571.  I'll write an answer to reflect that. Thanks